# Dynamically Build SQL query with varying number of WHERE clauses with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, crud

Looking to know how to efficiently build SQL queries that will have a varying number of OR/WHERE clauses. The goal is to reduce the number of database calls.

Currently, a method loops through a list of transaction ids that will be changing constantly, and for each id, it makes a call searching for each. The list of ids will get very large, and this will become very expensive db process.

## Current Implementation

#### Service Class

```
public List<RawTransactionsDAO> getAll(){
  ArrayList Integer ids = {1,2,3,4,5};
  
  ArrayList<Transactions> ls = new ArrayList<>();

  for(Integer id : ids){
    List<Transactions> transactions = transactionsRepository.getById();
    ls.add(transactions);
  }
  
  return ls;
}
```

#### Repository Class

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE id = :id ", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Transactions> getById(Integer id);
```

## Ideal Implementation

I would like to know how to do the following, without having to make a DB call for every id

#### Service Class

```
public List<RawTransactionsDAO> getAll(){
  ArrayList Integer ids = {1,2,3,4,5};
  
  ArrayList<Transactions> ls = transactionsRepository.getByIds(ids);
  
  return ls;
}
```

#### Repository Class

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE " + 
            "id = :id OR " +
            "id = :id OR " +
            ...
              // Add OR clause for every id provided
            ...
            , nativeQuery = true)
public List<Transactions> getByIds(ArrayList<Transactions> ids);
```

I tried making a loop that calls the DB every time, but it is too expensive to make this many calls.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE id in (....)` or `SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE id in (select otherid from otherTable)`